# How to kill both process and subprocess?

Tags: process, kill

I asked  [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893473/read-multiple-lines-from-subprocess-popen-stdout/3893654#3893654) to know how to get multiple lines of message from Python's subprocess module.

The problem is that in the course of testing, I had to kill the python process that runs gnuchess process. Using ^c in the command line seems to kill the python process, but not the gnuprocess.

For killing gnuchess, I get the pid with **ps aux | grep gnuchess** and run **kill -9 PID**. Are there other methods to kill both python and gnuchess process?

Comment: Random sidenote: You can use `pkill` to kill a process by name, so your `ps aux | grep gnuchess` and `kill -9 PID` can just become `pkill -9 gnuchess`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a standard method, if the programs cooperate. Run `kill -- -42` where 42 is the pid of the parent process. This sends a signal to all the processes in the [*process group*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) lead by process 42 (the minus sign before the pid means process group).

Normally, if you run your python script from a shell prompt and it simply forks `gnuchess`, the two processes should remain in the same process group. But this doesn't seem to be the case, since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGINT` to the whole foreground process group.

Gnuchess might be in its own process group because it made itself a session leader (but I don't know why it would do this), or because you've double-forked it (python forks a shell which forks gnuchess). A double fork is probably avoidable, but I can't tell you how without seeing your code.

---

A reasonably reliable and POSIX-compliant way of finding the pid of the `gnuchess` process is

```
gnuchess_pids=$(ps -A -o pid= -o cmd= | awk '$2 ~ /(^|\/)gnuchess$/ {print $1}')
```

Specific unix variants may have better ways of achieving this, such as `pgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pkill <processname>
```